# Navigation properties not being loaded from database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having a problem loading entities from an EF 4.3 Code First database.
I've simplified my code down to this working sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace CodeFirst {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
            Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

            using (Context context = new Context()) { 
                A a = new A { B = new B { Foo = 1 } };
                context.As.Add(a);
                context.SaveChanges();
                Print(context); // B has ID=1, Foo=1
            }

            using (Context context = new Context()) { 
                Print(context); // B is null
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Print(Context context) {
            A a = context.As.Single();
            Console.WriteLine("A: ID=" + a.Id);
            if (a.B == null) {
                Console.WriteLine("B: null");
            }
            else { 
                Console.WriteLine("B: ID=" + a.B.Id + ", Foo=" + a.B.Foo);
            }
        }
    }

    class Context : DbContext {
        public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    }

    class A {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public B B { get; set; }
    }

    class B {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
A: ID=1
B: ID=1, Foo=1
A: ID=1
B: null
```

In this sample code, for some reason when I retrieve `A` in a new `Context`, its subproperty `B` is `null`.  If I set a breakpoint and connect to the database at the point where `B` is `null`, everything looks to be in order:

```
Table: A
--------
Id    B_Id
1     1

Table: B
--------
Id    Foo
1     1
```

I'm just trying to learn Code First, so I may have a gross misunderstanding here, but this seems very strange to me.  Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers provided so far are unnecessarily cumbersome.

Just make your entity classes public and declare your navigation properties as `virtual`, and EF will load them lazily (i.e. on demand)

The `DbContext` must be open (i.e. not disposed) when you access the navigation property for this to work.

Comment: Making this change: `public virtual B B { get; set; }` didn't change the output of the code above.  Did I misinterpret?

Comment: I have just ran your exact code, and marking B as virtual produces the expected output. Did you forget to recompile something?

Comment: Just did a full clean and rebuild... B is still coming out as null.  I'm using EF 4.3 if it matters...

Comment: Just tried 4.3 and it works. Would you like to share your full solution somewhere?

Comment: OK, got it. Your classes must be public (otherwise, EF can't subclass them to create the proxies)

Comment: Aha, awesome.  Good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need Include them.

You need do something like this:

```
var aWithNavProperties = As.Where(a=>a.Id==id).Include(a=>a.B).Single();
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this was the general idea - just not quite correct syntactically.

Comment: I don't know what you mean not correct syntactically, but i strongly recommend use type safe Include(a=>a.B) and not use Include("B")

Comment: I agree on preferring type safe - when I tried using `Include` in that way, I got a syntax error.  It must have been my own error, and when I saw the other answer, I incorrectly assumed that there were no non-string overloads.  It is working now.

Comment: Note on the syntax here... the strongly typed version of `Include` is an extension method in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, so that needs to be included.  I was missing that in my other code, which was why this method wasn't working for me at first.

Answer (score 0):

By default Entity Framework only joins tables (and this is what navigation properties usually mao to, Joins) when explicitly told to do so. You can use the [`Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method:

```
var a = context.As.Include("B").Single();
```

You can also load properties after loading the entity itself. This is an implementation of the Lazy Loading pattern (which should be handled with care, it can be a real PITA)

```
var a = context.As.Single();
// some other code
if (!a.BReference.IsLoaded())
    a.BReference.Load();
```